# Iterar repetidamente sobre archivo parseado mediante csv.reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Estoy tratando de hacer un filtro de búsqueda de un archivo tsv, donde el usuario ingrese los filtros para visualizar los datos que quiere iterando sobre el fichero. El código que estoy estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import csv

with open("results.tsv") as tsvF:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter='\t')
    encabezado = next(reader)
    print(encabezado)

    for indice, col_enc in enumerate(encabezado):
        print(indice, col_enc)


    yearini = input("Desde el año: ")


    years, magnitudes, locations = [],[],[]
    for col in reader:
        year = col[2]
        if year > yearini:
            years.append(year)
            magnitud = float(col[9])
            magnitudes.append(magnitud)
            location = col[19]
            locations.append(location)

    for ind in range(0, len(years)):
       print(years[ind], ":", magnitudes[ind], '-', locations[ind])

    magini = input("Desde :")


    years, magnitudes, locations = [],[],[]
    for col in reader:
       magnitud = col[9]
       if magini > magnitud:
           magnitudes.append(magnitud)
           year = float(col[2])
           years.append(year)
           loation = col[19]
           locations.append(location)

    for ind in range(0, len(years)):
        print(magnitudes[ind], ":", years[ind], '-', locations[ind])
```

Con este código, el primer `print(years[ind], ":", magnitudes[ind], '-', locations[ind])` si funciona pero en el mismo `print` del último ciclo  no me muestra los datos como lo hace el primero.

Comment: Hola Diego Sanchez, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta iniciando por el titulo**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

`reader` **es un iterador**, lo que significa que cuando haces:

```
for col in reader:
```

**consumes todas los items del mismo (filas del archivo)**, por lo que cuando intentas iterar de nuevo sobre él, con el segundo `for col in reader`, iteras sobre un iterable vacío, por lo que lógicamente el filtrado no tiene lugar y el último `for` no imprime nada porque `years`, `magnitudes` y `locations` son listas vacías.

Si no puedes agrupar el código en una sola iteración sobre el fichero lo que puedes hacer es volver a colocar el cursor al inicio del mismo de nuevo:

```
import csv

with open("results.tsv") as tsvF:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter='\t')
    encabezado = next(reader)

    for col in reader:
        pass

    tsvF.seek(0)  # Volvemos a colocar el cursor al inicio del fichero
    next(reader)  # Volvemos a consumir el encabezado

    for col in reader:
        pass
```

Otra opción dependiendo del tamaño de tu fichero sería almacenar el contenido del archivo al completo en memoria, en una lista por ejemplo, e iterar sobre ella cuantas veces quieras:

```
import csv

with open("a.csv") as tsvF:
    reader = csv.reader(tsvF, delimiter='\t')

    encabezado = next(reader)   # Primera fila, encabezado
    filas = list(reader)        # Resto de filas

    # Sobre la lista puedes iterar cuantas veces quieras

    for fila in filas:
        pass

    for fila in filas:
        pass
```

---

Si lo único que quieres es imprimir los datos lo lógico sería no crear las tres listas, sino simplemente imprimir en el propio for encargado de iterar sobre las filas. Si necesitas las listas para otra cosa, entonces es más eficiente y más legible (en mi opinión) usar `zip`:

```
for year, mag, loc in zip(years, magnitudes, locations):
    print("{} : {} - {}".format(year, mag, loc))
```

O si usas Python >= 3.6 usar literales de cadena formateados:

```
for year, mag, loc in zip(years, magnitudes, locations):
    print(f"{year} : {mag} - {loc}")
```